# how to set sequential positive colorbar range with lowest value in the middle of colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am trying to set a colorbar, and I understand clim can do that. I cannot figure out how you set it so that the middle colorbar value is the smallest 1, with for example, a range of 1 to 52?

I am doing this because I have week numbers, but I do not want to show big jumps in the color from December to January (values 52 and 1)

EDIT: I am talking about the colors so that the ends of the colorbar are similar in color but the middle is the most different color. I do not want to change the values in the colorbar

Comment: Your question doesn't really make any sense! How do you logically make middle of a range it's minimum? There will be a jump, no matter what.

Comment: @anishtain4 i think he's talking about the colors. but i don't know how to use [`clim`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.clim)

Comment: so what you want is the colors to be `np.abs(week-26)` instead of `week`, but you don't want to change the values. Can you at least show a plot or something of what is going on now and what you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is a cyclic colormap. As of now, matplotlib only provides one single cyclic colormap, namely `"hsv"`. You may however define your own colormap easily and make sure it's cyclic, e.g. using the colors `["gold", "red", "black", "navy", "gold"]` where the first and the last color are the same.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
plt.rcParams['lines.markersize'] = 12

x = np.arange(200)
y = np.ones(200)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y, c=x % 52, marker="|" )

ax.scatter(x,y-1, c=x % 52, cmap="hsv", marker="|" )

colors = ["gold", "red", "black", "navy", "gold"]
cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", colors)
ax.scatter(x,y-2, c=x % 52, cmap=cmap, marker="|" )

ax.set_yticks([-1,0,1])
ax.set_yticklabels(["custom", "hsv", "viridis", ])
ax.margins(y=0.4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `clim` for what you want. instead:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
inferno = get_cmap('inferno').colors
new_cmap = ListedColormap(inferno+inferno[::-1])
```

[image: mid-centered cmap]

Comment: It seems this answer explains how to use `clim` which may be useful for some people, but how exactly does that relate to the question?

Comment: much better ;-)